# Where are Exchange Web Services: ExtendedPropertyDefinition IDs defined?

Tags: web-services, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

In researching how to use Exchange Web Services, I see examples like this

```
Dim PR_DELETED_ON As New ExtendedPropertyDefinition(26255, MapiPropertyType.SystemTime)
Dim PR_SEARCH_KEY As New ExtendedPropertyDefinition(12299, MapiPropertyType.Binary)
```

That first parameter is an int that represents the property ID.  Can anyone give me a pointer to where those ID numbers are defined?

Comment: I also came across this example in Koders:

http://www.koders.com/csharp/fidC0A348320DDB0703C4134B902C3DCBA9AF2438F0.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are called [Microsoft Exchange Property Tags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526844(EXCHG.10).aspx) and can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526844(EXCHG.10).aspx)

Comment: this is for exchange 2003, do you by chance have the link for 2007 and 2010 properties?

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't been working with Exchange lately and while I was working with it I never came across what you are asking for.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [Outlook Spy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/). It can tell you those numbers. There is a screen shot on that site that shows how to get them.

Comment: This tool was very helpful. It shows lots of good info on each message and folder. And best of all it's free.

Comment: this tool is helpful, though I wasn't able to install it on my win 7 office 2010 box.