# Are there publics Enums for ExtendedPropertyDefinition IDs?

Tags: powershell, enums, exchangewebservices

Much like in the example from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045233/where-are-exchange-web-services-extendedpropertydefinition-ids-defined) I see many code snippets on the web using magic numbers when making ExtendedPropertyDefinition. Example:

```
Dim PR_DELETED_ON As New ExtendedPropertyDefinition(26255, MapiPropertyType.SystemTime)
Dim PR_SEARCH_KEY As New ExtendedPropertyDefinition(12299, MapiPropertyType.Binary)
```

I have *sort of* found a [reference location for these on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815492%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). I can look them up individually as supposed to one large table. Here is the one for `PR_DELETED_ON` like in the above example

> ```
>  +------------------------+---------------+
>  | Associated properties: | PR_SEARCH_KEY |
>  +------------------------+---------------+
>  | Identifier:            | 0x300B        |
>  +------------------------+---------------+
>  | Data type:             | PT_BINARY     |
>  +------------------------+---------------+
>  | Area:                  | ID properties |
>  +------------------------+---------------+
> ```

0x300b being 12299 in decimal

I hate magic numbers so I was looking for an enum for this in the EWS API. I wrote this snippet to (hopefully) show me all the enums exposed.

```
$obj = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Program Files (x86)\EWSManagedAPI\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll")
$obj.GetTypes() | Where-object{$_.isenum -and ($_.ispublic -or $_.isnestedpublic)} | ForEach-Object{
    $props = @{Name = $_.FullName}
    [enum]::GetValues($_) | ForEach-Object{
        $props.Integer = [int64]$_ 
        $props.Text = $_
        [pscustomobject]$props
    } 
}
```

I didn't see anything in the output that matched what I was looking at above. Does anyone know if there is a preexisting enum for these properties? If not that is fine. I just assumed there would be something out there.

Not the end of the world but I couldn't find them myself. Might explain why code snippets keep referencing to them.

Comment: I guess the semantic names are present only in C++ header whereas compiled applications use the bare numbers. Although you can try searching the windows, outlook, office, common files folders for PR_SEARCH_KEY and so on.

Comment: Don't know if it helps but it exists in some commercial libraries [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/api/net/email/aspose.email.mapi/knownpropertylist)

Answer (score 2):

No there is nothing in the EWS Managed API for this and AFAIK there is no master list maintained by Microsoft. There are also different types of Properties eg Tagged and Named properties and to use an Extended property in EWS you need to first define and tell Exchange to either return or set that property so EWS doesn't allow you to enumerate all the Extended properties on a Item like MAPI. The closest list that I know of is the one from the EWSEditor which is pretty comprehensive https://ewseditor.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#EWSEditor/PropertyInformation/KnownExtendedPropertiesData.cs . The Mapi include files also have a good list eg https://github.com/openchange/openchange/blob/master/properties_enum.h (but these are only tagged properties).

Comment: Seeing you all over the place lately. Love your blog the way. thanks for the conformation